# predicted_classes = model.predict(np.array(X_text_train)) ValueError: Error

Tags: python, deep-learning

```
model.fit(
    {'main_input': X_text_train, 'aux_input': X_number_train},
    {'main_output': y_train, 'aux_output': y_train},
    validation_data=[
        {'main_input': X_text_test, 'aux_input': X_number_test}, 
        {'main_output': y_test, 'aux_output': y_test}
    ],
    epochs=20,
    batch_size=2048
)

predicted_classes = model.predict(np.array(X_text_train))
#predicted_classes = model.predict(np.array(X_text_train), np.array(X_number_train))
#predicted_classes = model.predict(X_text_train)
```

Getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: 
the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the 
size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the
following list of 1 arrays: 
[array([[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 7614, 450, 963],
[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 28, 3, 1259],
[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 332, 136, 140],
...,
[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 1174, ...
```

Comment: I need more info. How are you construction the est and train arrays?

Comment: data set  and the code I uploaded in GitHub https://github.com/sunilchinnahalli/bot-or-not/blob/master/twitBG50.ipynb      https://github.com/sunilchinnahalli/bot-or-not/blob/master/new_labeled_tweets11.csv